# Are idx_scan statistics reset automatically (default)?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, statistics

I was looking at the tables (`pg_stat_user_indexes` and `pg_stat_user_tables`) and discovered many indices that are not being used.

But before I think about doing any operations to remove these indices, I need to understand what period was the analysis of this data (`idx_scan`), has it been since the database was created?

In the `pg_stat_database` table (column `stats_reset`) there is a date that normally is today or up to 15 days ago, but does this process interfere with the tables I mentioned above?

No command `pg_stat_reset()` was executed.

Does the `pg_stat_reset()` command clear the tables (`pg_stat_user_indexes` and `pg_stat_user_tables`)?

My goal is to understand the period of data collected so that I can make a decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statistics are cumulative and are kept from the time of cluster creation on.

So if you see the `pg_stat_database.stats_reset` change regularly, there must be somebody or something doing that explicitly with the `pg_stat_reset()` function.

Doing so is somewhat problematic, because this resets all statistics, including those in `pg_stat_user_tables` which govern when autovacuum and autoanalyze take place. So after a reset these will be a little out of whack until autoanalyze has collected new statistics.

The better way is to take regular snapshots and calculate the difference.

You are right that you should collect data over a longer time before you determine if an index can be canned or not. For example, some activity may only take place once a month, but require certain indexes.

Before dropping indexes, consider that indexes also serve other purposes besides being scanned:

- They can be `UNIQUE` or back a constraint, in which case they serve a purpose even when they are never scanned.
- Indexes on expressions make PostgreSQL collect statistics on the distribution of the indexed expression, which can have a notable effect on query planning and the quality of your execution plans.

You could use the query in [this blog](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/get-rid-of-your-unused-indexes/) to find all the indexes that serve no purpose at all.

Answer (score 1):

Only superuser is allowed to reset statistic. Query planer depends on statistic.

Use snapshots:

```
CREATE TABLE stat_idx_snap_m10_d29_16_12 AS SELECT * FROM pg_stat_user_indexes;
CREATE TABLE stat_idx_snap_m10_d29_16_20 AS SELECT * FROM pg_stat_user_indexes;
```

Analyze difference any time later:

```
SELECT
  s2.relid, s2.indexrelid, s2.schemaname, s2.relname, s2.indexrelname,
  s2.idx_scan - s1.idx_scan as idx_scan,
  s2.idx_tup_read - s1.idx_tup_read as idx_tup_read,
  s2.idx_tup_fetch - s1.idx_tup_fetch as idx_tup_fetch
FROM stat_idx_snap_m10_d29_16_20 s2
FULL OUTER JOIN stat_idx_snap_m10_d29_16_12 s1
  ON s2.relid = s1.relid AND s2.indexrelid = s1.indexrelid
ORDER BY s2.idx_scan - s1.idx_scan ASC;
```